# How to left-align all text and right-align all numbers in a HTML table using CSS, but without using a class?

Tags: html, css

Suppose I have the following table. How do I left align all text and right align all numbers with CSS? The caveat is that I cannot use a class (the reason is that Python is used to produce giant HTML tables).

```html
 <table>
  <tr>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>More data</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> -1234.1596 </td>
    <td> -0.15 </td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 3714.8146 </td>
    <td>0.48</td>
    <td>Centro comercial </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What does "without using a class" mean? Can you not use a stylesheet? Can you not modify the HTML? Can you only use element type selectors? Please revise to clarify. Your Python explanation doesn't explain anything--the backend is exactly the place to set up classes. If you have to only use _inline_ styles, say that. If your numbers are always in the first and second columns, and you want a selector to target those, say _that_.

Answer (score 0):

Set the table to default to left-aligned text everywhere, then make a CSS class that sets the text alignment to the right and apply that only to the table cells you need it on.

```css
table {
  text-align: left;
}

table tr td:nth-child(1),
table tr td:nth-child(2){
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Data</th>
    <th>More data</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
    <th>Header 3</th>
    <th>Header 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> -1234.1596 </td>
    <td> -0.15 </td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 3714.8146 </td>
    <td>0.48</td>
    <td>Centro comercial </td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I updated the question. I forgot that defining seperate classes is very messy in my case.

Comment: So you want to do this only in CSS but without touching the HTML?  Ok, see my updated answer.  You just have to specify which column numbers need the be styled differently

Comment: @isherwood the `<th>` elements are center aligned by default, which is why I added that.

Comment: Fair enough, but column headers are rarely aligned with the column content. I'd want them to stay centered.

Comment: Well, thankfully this is just a simple example and the CSS can be customized as needed